# Finding users in AD

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I am trying to use a text file of users e-mail address to find the samaccountname names of the corresponding users.

```
Clear-Host

Import-Module ActiveDirectory

$File = "C:\T2\Users.csv"

$Users = Get-Content $File

ForEach ($User in $Users)

{ Get-ADUser -Filter * | Where { $_.EmailAddress -eq $User } | Select SamAccountName -ExpandProperty SamAccountName }
```

I am trying to understand what I am doing wrong

Comment: Use `Import-Csv` instead of `Get-Content` and it should resolve your problem.  Also, NEVER EVER use `Get-ADUser -Filter *` as you query the entire AD structure for each user.  If you do that, at least store it in a variable at the start so you only do it *once*.  Instead of `Where-Object`, you should do `-Filter "EmailAddress -eq '$($User.EmailAddress)'"`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If your file is actually a `.csv` (comma-separated values), what you're doing is getting raw string content with `Get-Content`.  There is a cmdlet, `Import-Csv`, that will take your CSV and turn it into a powershell object so you can iterate over it and access the headers as properties like you're trying to do in your code:

```
$users = Import-Csv -Path '/path/to/file.csv'
```

Then in your loop, you can clean up and *speed up* your code by *not* querying the entire AD tree for each user:

```
foreach ($user in $users)
{
    Get-ADUser -Filter "EmailAddress -eq '$($user.EmailAddress)'" |
        Select-Object -ExpandProperty SamAccountName
}
```

---

Super simplified version:

```
#requires -Module ActiveDirectory
foreach ($user in Import-Csv -Path '/path/to/file.csv')
{
    (Get-ADUser -Filter "EmailAddress -eq '$($user.EmailAddress)'").SamAccountName
}
```

Comment: I figured the simplified version would be `Import-Csv 'C:\T2\Users.csv'|%{Get-ADUser -Filter "EmailAddress -eq '$($_.EmailAddress)'"}|% SamAccountName`

Comment: @TheMadTechnician I like to avoid pipelines in scenarios where there may be a significant number of users as they can impede the speed of the commands as well.

Comment: @thenadtechnician, why are you using `foreach samaccountname` instead of `select samaccountname` ??

Comment: @RobertCotterman because there is more than one parameterset to `ForEach-Object`.  You can also enumerate an object's members.

Comment: I'll have to test it. Sounds interesting. So what I'm hearing is that foreach will enumerate objects with a samaccountname property? Rather than select just displaying samaccountname even blank ones?

Comment: @RobertCotterman Not so. It returns `$null` for non-existent properties still.  It has less application since PSv3+ added member enumeration `$collection.Property`